# Time complexity calculation of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

What is the complexity of the below program:

```
void function(int n)
{
int i, j, k , count =0;
for(i=n/2; i<=n; i++)
  for(j=1; j=j + n/2<=n; j++)
      for(k=1; k<=n; k= k * 2)
         count++;
}
```

Now as per my understanding the outer loop executes n/2 times. Inner loop executes n/2 times and third inner loop executes the log n times. Now if we denote the time complexity of algorithm as a function T(n).

> T(n)=n/2*n/2*log n
> =n^2/4*log n

Now for very large input size of n term log n becomes too small in comparison with the term n^2. So per my understanding the time complexity of the algorithm must be O(n^2). But I have checked the answer of this above program it says the answer is O(n^2logn).

Why can't we ignore the term log n for larger values of n? Or is the calculation I have done wrong?

Comment: Yes, log(n) is smaller than polynomial, but when it's multiplied it's still a factor. O(log(n)) is slower than O(n), but O(nlogn) is a thing, and it's similar to what you've got. O(nlogn) != O(n). A graph could illustrate this well.

Comment: Thanks keyser. Say for example if we have time complexity  T(n)=n^3+n^2+n then for very large values of n we ignore the term n^2 and n then why can't we do the same thing over here ?

Comment: Yes, we do, because they're separate. Asymptotically the other ones won't have any notable impact, but asymptotically, O(nlogn) grows faster than O(n), since log(n) is more than a constant. I liked benji's illustration of how they're removed.

Comment: `n^3 + n^2` is less than `n^3 + n^3 = 2*n^3` which is `O(n^3)`

Comment: When you multiply you get a different order of magnitude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore only the constant values. If n increases, log(n) also increases.

Comment: Thanks axiac. But say for example if we have time complexity T(n)=n^3+n^2+n then for very large values of n we ignore the term n^2 and n then why can't we do the same thing over here ?

Comment: @Beast You can ignore n^2 and n because you add them to n^3 not multiply like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If we make assumption that your algorihtm has got running time function (is not exactly true):

```
T(n)=n/2*n/2*log n =n^2/4*log n= an^2*log(n)
```

You can do formal asymptotic analysis:

[image]

We can easily  proof that we can find c1 and c2 to fulfill:

[image]

So finally you can say that your algorithm has got complexity:

[image]